# How to get CSS from SCSS file in angular to upload in to a server

Tags: css, angular, sass

Here is my need:

I have created a `angular library` which is used by number of applications. the library has the all styles file as ".scss" extension. in case of any update in library each application require to build the `angular-library`, instead I decided to keep the library scss/css files in server. so it will automatically updated with all apps.

as a try i uploaded the '.scss' file, but it's not working after i added the file in `index.html`
the question is:

1. how to include the `style.scss` file in other applications - if not possible then
2. hot to convert `scss` files in to `css` file while i do library build and same can uploaded in server

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

at the root of project in angular.json u can add styles files from libraries (like global syle.scss) and angular application will convert them automatically